# Having other subprocess in queue wait until a certain flag is set

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

The problem is still on the drawing board so far, so I can go for another better suited approach. The situation is like this:

We create a queue of n-processes, each of which execute independently of the other tasks in the queue itself. They do not share any resources etc. However, we noticed that sometimes (depending on queue parameters) a process `k`'s behaviour might depend on existence of a flag specific to `k+1` process. This flag is to be set in a DynamoDB table, and therefore; the execution could fails.

What I am currently searching around for is a method so that I can set some sort of waiters/suspenders in my tasks/workers so that they poll until the flag is set in the DynamoDB table, and meanwhile let the other subprocess take up the CPU.

The setting of this boolean value is done a little early in the processes themselves. The dependent part of the process comes much later.

Comment: You can easily do it if you can change the source of the process that needs to wait on the flag.

Comment: @AJPennster But, lets say I launch 3 processes in the pool and my `n` is 12, whereas my `k` is at index 1 and `k+1` is at 7. Now, the `k+1`th process would execute only when the previous processes have been executed, whereas my k-th one would freeze until the k+1-th has setup the flag value. Which was why I want to suspend my processes after setting the flags so that other processes can start execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we went ahead with creating **n** number of processes instead of having a suspender. This would not be the ideal approach, but for the time being; it solves the issue at hand.

I'd still love a better method to achieve the same.